# Probability of one Poisson variable being greater than another

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Given two Poisson distributions with different λ values, if each were to produce a single random variable, is there closed-form expression for calculating the probability of one random variable being greater than the other?

Comment: There isn't a nice closed-form expression for this, as you will find if you attempt to compute e.g. $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{e^{-\lambda _1-\lambda _2} \lambda _2^k \lambda _1^n}{k! n!} $$

Comment: Yeah, should have mentioned in the question I was looking for a closed-form expression. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your Question if the wording  can be improved.  For example the current phrasing could be interpreted in a trivial sense, that one of the two random variables will exceed the other with probability one (because the alternative is for the random variables to be exactly equal).

Comment: Perhaps of interest: the difference of two Poisson random variables follows a [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution). You'll notice that Wikipedia doesn't give an expression for the CDF. Also, this question is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297299

Answer (score 7):

Take two poisson random variables $A$ and $B$ with means $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$ respectively. We see that

$$P(A > B) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} P(A > B | B = k)P(B = k)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(A \geq k + 1)P(B = k)
= \sum_{k= 0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{l=k+1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda_A^{l}
e^{-\lambda_A}}{l!} \right)\frac{\lambda_B^k e^{-\lambda_B}}{k!}.$$

Generally, this is difficult to calculate for a general result, but the key idea behind this is to condition on the value of one of the variables.

Comment: Conditioning is unnecessary (and certainly not "key" here).

Comment: why? please provide some argumentation

Comment: @Did Could you please show how to compute $\mathbb P(A>B)$ without conditioning?