# Probability of a Poisson variable being greater than k others

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, order-statistics, poissons-equation

If one has multiple Poisson random variables (with potentially different lambda parameter), how can one theoretically find the probability that one of those variables is greater than the others?

That is, assume you have $k$ random variables $X_{i=1...k}$ s.t. $X_i \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda_i)$, where lambdas are not necessarily the same. I want to find $P(X_i > X_j) \ \forall i \neq j : 1 \leq j \leq k$.

I am aware that this may not have a closed form. In fact, I think it is just a generalization of what can be seen in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843049/probability-of-one-poisson-variable-being-greater-than-another). However, I am struggling with how to write down such generalization: at first, I thought that it would be just a product of the calculation of the formula in the above mentioned question, for each pairwise comparison. However, this is wrong, since the pairwise comparisons are not independent events. That is, $P(X_i > X_j) $ is not independent from $P(X_i > X_h) \ \forall h \neq i,j : 1\leq h \leq k$.

What is the correct formula for finding the probability that the realization of a given Poisson random variable will will be greater than the realizations of $k-1$ other random variables?

Answer (score 1):

For $3$ random variables for example, the probability that $X_1$ is greater than both $X_2$ and $X_3$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr(X_1= k+1)\Pr(X_2\leq k)\Pr(X_3\leq k)$$ assuming the random variables are independent.  Then fill in the formulas for these probabilities, just as in the question you linked.  The generalization to an arbitrary number of random variables should be clear.

This will be difficult to evaluate, I should think.  You might have better luck with simulation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answering! One note, two follow-up questions. (1) note: in your answer, $k$ means something different than in my question; (2) question: my impression is that you are conditioning on $X_1$, so why $Pr(X_1 \geq k +1)$? Shouldn't it be the PMF of $X_1$ there instead, like $Pr(X_1 = k)$ (2) question: difficult to evaluate in the sense of deciding when to stop looping over $k$? I was under the impression that this would converge (up to tiny changes)

Comment: @roSh 1)In my answer, $k$ is a dummy variable; it doesn't really mean anything.  2) That was a typo; thanks.  3) That was just an impression, I guess, although I was thinking about the case where you have many random variables, say $10$.  You might be right about convergence.  I think it would depend on the various $\lambda_i$, though.