# $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$ for $X,Y$ two Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, binomial-coefficients, poisson-distribution

Two teams have to play a final of a tournament. Team A score a number of goals that can be shaped like a random variable $X \sim Poi(\lambda_{A}=2.5)$. Team B score a number of goals that can be shaped like a random variable $Y \sim Poi(\lambda_{B}=2)$. The variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

- 1) What is the probability that A win?
- 2) What is the probability of a tie?
- 3) What is the probability of an over (that is the sum of goals of two teams is greater than $4$)?

---

I think I've solved only the point 2).

Knowing that $H=${total number of goals}$\sim Poi(4.5)\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(H=h)=\frac{e^{-4.5}4.5^h}{h!}$ and setting $T=X-Y$, I wrote:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(T=0)&=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X=s,Y=s)\\&=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X=s,Y=s,H=2s)\\&=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(H=2s)\mathbb{P}(X=s,Y=s|H=2s)\\&=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(H=2s)\mathbb{P}(X=s|H=2s)\\&=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-4.5}4.5^{2s}}{2s!}\binom{2s}{s}p^s(1-p)^{2s-s}\\&=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-4.5}4.5^{2s}[p(1-p)]^s}{s!s!}
\end{align*}$$

Is it correct?

Instead, I find it difficult to formalize $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X+Y>4)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are discrete variables. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Are there any more information on this question or is that it?

Comment: @matcha_ That's it.

Comment: hint: try drawing the graph for X+Y=4 , and you can also treat P( X = 4 - Y).

Comment: Related question: [Probability of one Poisson variable being greater than another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843049/probability-of-one-poisson-variable-being-greater-than-another)

Comment: So is the total number of goals=4 a condition or you have to compute it for an arbitrary number of goals?

Comment: Hallo @FrancescoTotti. Point 3) is immediate. You just have to observe that $(X+Y) \sim Po(\lambda=4.5)$

Comment: @Alex It's a condition given in the text.

Comment: You do have part 2 okay, but Note: $p=2.5/4.5$.

Comment: @FrancescoTotti then I don't quite understand (3): how can the sum>4 if the total number is 4

Comment: It is greater than four if it is not 0,1,2,3,or 4. $$\small\mathsf P(X+Y>4)=1-\sum_{z=0}^4 \mathsf P(X+Y=z)$$

Comment: @Alex Sorry, you're right. I edited. For point 3) I have to find $\mathbb{P}(X+Y>4)$.

Comment: Things might clear up if you look at them in the following context. If $Z:=X+Y$ then - as commented - it has Poisson distribution with parameter $4.5$. Under condition $Z=n$ the distribution of $X$ is binomial with parameters $n$ and $2.5/4.5=5/9$.

Answer (score 1):

For 1), given the condition you gave, you need to consider outcomes (4,0), (3,1)

For 2), again, given the condition (2,2), because you can't get a draw otherwise.

For 3), an integer $n$ can be a sum of two integers $\leq n$ in $n+1$ ways, so given independence you need the probability 
$$
P(X+Y=n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}P(X=k)P(Y=n-k)
$$
EDIT: for 3), also consider $X+Y=Z$, which is also Poisson with rate $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$.