# Game with Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, information-theory, poisson-distribution, decision-problems

**Problem introduction**

Let us consider the following problem.

We have 2 players Alice and Bob and they play a game which is about getting points. The player with most points wins. The points player get depend on their and opponent's strategies.

We know the Alice's and Bob's points that they get over a game come from Poisson distribution with parameters $w_a$, $w_b$.

Moreover we know that points what both players lose are also from a Poisson distribution with parameters $l_a$ and $l_b$ respectively.

We wish to know what are the probabilities that a player wins before the game starts.

**Possible solution**

Let $W_a$ and $W_b$ denote points that Alice and Bob get and $L_a$ and $L_b$ denote points that Alice and Bob lose.

P(Alice wins) = P($W_a > L_a$) = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(W_a = k) P(L_a < k)$

P(Alice wins) = P($W_a > W_b$) = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(W_a = k) P(W_b < k)$

P(Alice wins) = P($L_b > W_b$) = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(L_b = k) P(W_b < k)$

P(Alice wins) = P($L_b > L_a$) = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(L_b = k) P(L_a < k)$

For example if the means for $W_a$, $W_b$, $L_a$ and $L_b$ are $8$ $5$ $7$ and $2$, the above formulas give us following results: $0.55, 0.76, 0.09$ and $0.03$.

**Question**

Is there any way to combine all these approaches so that we take into account all $4$ variables and the best prediction?

PS: code to calculate numbers:
[image]

Comment: What are exactly the rules of winning? It seems that Alice wins if:
she got more points than bob OR she got more points than she lost OR bob lost more points than he won OR bob lost more points than Alice, and in all other cases she loses? So if she got more points than bob and lost more points than bob, she wins? Or should the winner be the one with the bigger $W-L$ and that's it?

Comment: The winner is the person with the higher **W - L**

Comment: I believe a good way to think about it any sport game, like basketball or soccer.

Answer (score 1):

The event Alice wins occurs when $W_a-L_a>W_b-L_b$ which is the same as $W_a+L_b>W_b+L_a$.
For two id Poisson RV $X_1,X_2$ with parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, we know that $X_1+X_2$ is Poisson RV with parameter $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$, so your question is to compute that probability that one Poisson RV (with parameter $w_a+l_b$) is bigger than the other (with parameter $w_b+l_a$).

As you can see here, [Probability of one Poisson variable being greater than another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843049/probability-of-one-poisson-variable-being-greater-than-another) , there isn't a nice answer.